# Managing provisioning of .NET MAUI app in csproj file

Tags: maui

I'm trying to understand how I need to handle provisioning of my .NET MAUI app because I keep running into issues with HotRestart. I realize some of the issues are due HotRetart bugs but I want to do my part right.

Here's my setup. I do most of my development on a Windows 11 PC and I want to be able to connect my iPhone to my PC via USB and use HotRestart to debug the app while I develop it. I then go to a remote Mac to both test and build my app.

I went through the process of creating a provisioning profile that is specific to the Mac and I have the following in `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignEntitlement>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlement>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: My Company, LLC (APPLEASSIGNEDIDHERE)</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>MyiOSProvisioningProfile</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My question is do I need a separate section in my `csproj` file for my PC where I want to use my iPhone with Hotrestart to debug the app? If so, what does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `iPhone Distribution` is used in the release mode not the debug mode. So you can remove it.

And then you can apply the **HotRestart** when debug just follow up the official document about the [Deploy an iOS app using hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0) step by step and choose **Configure Automatic Provisioning** by right-click your iOS project, go to Properties -> Build->iOS Bundle Signing, then select Developer (Automatic) for Signing Identity and the corresponding provisioning profile.

In addition, I see you added `<CodesignEntitlement>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlement>`, did you [add any capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/?tabs=macos) in your project? If so, you need to config the Provisioning Profile for it and import it into the PC or just pair to Mac when you debug the project.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to understand specifically: if I use both a Windows laptop and a Mac, do I need two sections for the code signing/provisioning stuff in the project file? Meaning one for the certs on Mac keychain and a second section to define the cert/provisioning profile I'd use on Windows? Trying to understand how this works for people who use multiple machines to develop an app.